# Get StageName Picklist Set\Sales Process based on RecordType

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, picklist, metadata, record-type

I have to create a Kanban view like Lightning component and to do that I need to list out Opportunity Stages based on Record Types. Using MetadataService I am able to to get all the picklist values on Opportunity except the sales process. I am using the following code:

```
string objName = 'Opportunity';
string recordTypeName = 'Minerals';
string fieldName = 'StageName';
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetadataServiceExamples.createService();
MetadataService.RecordType recordType = (MetadataService.RecordType) service.readMetadata
    ('RecordType',new String[] {objName+'.'+recordTypeName}).getRecords()[0];

for(MetadataService.RecordTypePicklistValue rpk : recordType.picklistValues){
    for(MetadataService.PicklistValue pk : rpk.values){
            System.debug(pk.fullname + '------' + rpk.picklist);

    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

My source:
https://www.mstsolutions.com/technical/get-picklist-entries-based-on-the-record-type/

Is there a way to modify this snippet to meet the requirements, or is there any other way I could achieve this in lightning components?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I appreciate your effort with the formatting, but we do things a bit differently here. You can read more about our [markup](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help documentation. I've fixed this one for you, so please feel free to peruse the docs at your leisure.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much!